# Configure Windows 7 Wireless at Windows Setup with Unattend?

Tags: windows, deployment, wifi, unattended

Is it possible to configure the wireless settings at deployment by customizing the Unattend.xml file?

Comment: Use WPA-Enterprise (with certificates). Win7 can be configured by GPO to automatically pull certificates and configured to use particular Wireless networks.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the [wireless profile export](http://goo.gl/qDVS8) it and do a wireless profile import during the oobe phase in [FirstLogonCommands](http://goo.gl/XGneI). But, doing what Chris S says would be easier to manage in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely do some settings ( Or all depending on how much work you wanna put into it), as you can use a tool like prossess monitor to find the changes being done by every setting and then deploy them in the installation.

But i would recommend deploying what you can via group policy, this way its simpler to change it when you have to. This also means the users cannot override the settings